# Consistent Hash of Database Table on Different Database Types

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, database, oracle

I have the same data table on various different database types (Microsoft SQL2005, MySql and IBM Informix, Oracle), and I need to generate a SHA-1 hash result over the data in the table that is the same across the different database types.

I am trying to determine the best way to accomplish this and so far this is what I have come up with:

- Using .NET SqlDataAdapter, select * from desired table into
  DataTable.
- Sort column names via List.Sort() to ensure consistent
  ordering between database types
- For each row, perform a hash as follows:

  - Convert each column value to a string and append to rowString, in the
    order determined above
  - Hash the entire rowString to obtain a rowHash and add this to a list.
- Next, sort all rowHash values by their SHA-1 value and hash the
  result to obtain the final table hash.  This should take care of
  issues where rows are returned in different order between different
  database types.

Will I encounter any issues with this implementation?  Such as data types from different databases causing different string results?

Also, is sorting necessary?  I am assuming that the column and row ordering is not guaranteed unless defined in the query and I want this to be as dynamic as possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add information about the table schema and your maximum estimate of the total amount of data. Also, is the data in the tables static, and are you generating the hash in order to compare the same table in two or more providers at a given point in time?

Comment: If I understand, you have the same data, stored in a single table, in multiple database servers using difference database server software. You wish to know if the data is indeed the same. And have decided to compute a hash value for the entire table and use that hash value to compare the differences.

Comment: What does equality mean in the face of differing definitions of null across the database server software? Oracle can not hold a zero character string `''` in a `varchar` or `varchar2` string, because they chose to make `''` equivalent to `null`. In other databases, at least MS SQL Server, `''` is not equivelent to `null`.

Comment: Alex: No, I cannot add any information to the table schema and only have read access.  The data is static, and yes the hash is used to compare the same table between multiple providers at any time.  Thanks

Comment: Shannon: Yes, that is what I am attempting to do

Comment: Shannon: Good point, I did not think of that.  I imagine nulls and empty strings could be handled during the client side hash as empty strings which should make them equal.  Thanks

Comment: If you simply concatenate the columns into a single row string you won't be able to tell the difference between `A,BC` and `AB,C`.  You may want to add the column number to each value.

Answer (score 1):

Watch out for numeric values, in particular with rounding and precision.